# Outlook no carga bien las imagenes

Tags: html, email, outlook

Estoy haciendo una firma de correo en HTML, la cual tiene 3 imágenes. Al momento de usarla en *Outlook*, carga la última imagen 3 veces, es decir, es como si para las 3 imágenes estuviera usando la misma ruta, es muy extraño.

El grueso de la plantilla lo hice a traves de Mailchimp, y luego hice alguna modificación del HTML resultante, pero no toqué nada que tenga que ver con las imágenes.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa y cómo solucionarlo?

El código es bastante extenso así que solamente pongo lo correspondiente a una de las imágenes:

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="mcnCaptionRightImageContent" valign="top">

            <img alt="" src="logo.jpg" width="260" height="76" style="max-width:260px; width: 260px; height: 76px; max-height: 76px;" class="mcnImage">

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algo de código que podamos ver?

Comment: Si y no... el grueso de la plantilla lo hice con Mailchimp, luego exporte el HTML para hacer algunas modificaciones, pero el tema de las imagenes no toqué nada...

Comment: Pues es bastante raro, ¿Se ven bien las imágenes fuera de outlook, viendo el HTML desde un navegador? Y estaria bien si pones todo el código aunque sea un poco largo para poder probarlo nosotros y ver si ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Si, fuera de eso se ve perfecto tanto en navegadores, como en thunderbird, como en el Mail de Mac... es más, el problema es en un Outlook 2007 que tengo en otro PC, en otro Outlook 2010 de otro ordenador tambien funciona bien. 

Podría pasarte el codigo por privado o algo?

Comment: Entonces el html está bien y tampoco es cosa de las imágenes. No tengo un outlook 2007 para probar pero tiene pinta de ser un bug o algo que esta mal en tu configuracion del outlook

Comment: Pues si es alguna configuracion espero encontrar el problema, no se te ocurre nada mas verdad? Gracias por cierto.

Comment: Agrega el código que usas para cargar ese html a outlook

Comment: A mi me sucedió algo muy anormal... Cuando hice una aplicación con Mailchimp y es que cuando lo probaba en local no me mostraba imagenes, pero cuando el sitio esta "live" ya se mostraban... Y eso es porque outlook te dice que es riesgo leer cosas de localhost.... puede ser algo parecido

Comment: @Cig eso es bastante probable pero lo curioso de este caso es que carga la misma imagen para tres rutas distintas, eso no lo he visto nunca

Comment: cierto... @blonfu

Comment: Otra idea que se me ocurre es la cache de Outlook, intenta cambiar de localización las imágenes así como sus nombres...

Comment: Lo de la caché de Outlook tambien lo intenté. Al final lo dejé como estaba porque el único Outlook donde fallaba era en un 2007 en concreto... quiero pensar que era alguna configuración o algo asi. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta ok tu código. Y tampoco es un bug de Outlook. Mas bien, el problema es que Outlook 2007 usa un motor de renderizado de html bastante precario, utiliza el motor de renderizado de Word 2007. Esto tiene muchisimas implicancias en el resultado final de tu email en ese cliente. Entre otros puntos:

- no hay soporte para imagenes background (HTML o CSS)
- no hay soporte para formularios
- no hay soportes para Flash u otros plugins
- no hay soporte para CSS flotante
- no hay soporte para remplazar los bullets de una lista desordenada por imágenes
- no hay soporte para GIF's animados

En [este link](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/outlook-2007-not-showing-images/) podes ver una consulta similar, donde la sugerencia es cambiar una configuración del lado de Internet Explorer, asegurarte que no esté en Modo Offline, por algun motivo eso bloquea el renderizado de las imágenes.

Como recomendación:

- No te preocupes por esa imagen rota en Outlook 2007, el porcentaje de
  clientes Outlook 2007 hace rato que no es importante.
- Si necesitas soporte para Outlook 2007, vas a tener que hacer una versión especial de tu html solo para ese cliente.

Como extra, te dejo un link super importante para tener en cuenta a la hora de hacer emails. Es un estado de los emails armado por Litmus todos los años. [Aca podes descargar el PDF](https://litmus.com/lp/2016-state-of-email-report) con información valiosísima a la hora de entender si vale la pena o no gastar esfuerzos en hacer que tu email funcione para tal o cual cliente

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la aportación Santiago! :)

Comment: Espero sirva! Mira el reporte de Litmus State of Email 2016. Esa información es clave para una efectiva campaña de mailing!